# Erro "SIGSEGV" ao receber um pacote grande de dados

Tags: c, c++, socket, posix

Ola,

estou enfrentando um Erro "SIGSEGV" ao receber um pacote grande de dados com a função recv da biblioteca  utilizando linguagem C em um sistema Posix - UNIX, se alguma alma puder me ajudar um agradeço.

buffer:

```
char ls_buffer_PPouAUT[2048] =  {0};
```

rcv:

```
    ln_retorno_receive          =   recv
                                    (
                                        in_socket_handler,
                                        ls_buffer_PPouAUT,
                                        sizeof(ls_buffer_PPouAUT),
                                        0
                                    );

    ls_buffer_PPouAUT[ln_retorno_receive]           =   0x00;
```

Socket:

```
int     SocketConnect
    (
        char*           as_host,
        int             an_port
    )
{

int
ln_connection_status            =   9;

//
// Variavel que guarda o retorno
//
GEDI_e_Ret      ret;

//
// Cria o Socket
//
// AF_INET      =   ARPA INTERNET PROTOCOLS
// SOCK_STREAM  =   orientado a conexao
// 0            =   protocolo padrao para o tipo escolhido -- TCP
in_socket_handler           =   socket  (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

//
// Informa para conectar no server
//
// IP do servidor
server.sin_family           =   AF_INET;
// familia ARPANET
server.sin_addr.s_addr      =   inet_addr(  as_host );
// Porta - hton = host to network short (2bytes) ou htons para mais
server.sin_port             =   htons ( an_port );

//
// Limpa varivavel
//
memset  (
            &(server.sin_zero),
            0x00,
            sizeof (server.sin_zero)
        );

//
// Inicia comunicacao com server
//
if (
        connect (
                    in_socket_handler,
                    (struct sockaddr *) &server,
                    sizeof (server)
                )
        < 0
    )
{
    //
    // Se ocoreu uma falha
    //
    GEDI_LCD_DrawString(10, FONT_HEIGHT*10, FONT_WIDTH*1, FONT_HEIGHT*1,
            " Falha ao criar socket!                           ");
    GEDI_CLOCK_Delay(1000);

    ln_connection_status            =   9;
}

else
{
    //
    //  Se conectou com sucesso
    //
    ln_connection_status            =   0;

}

//
// Retorna o status da conexao.
//
return  ln_connection_status;
}
```

Obrigado.
Lucas

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Quando você diz "ao receber um pacote grande", onde exatamente ocorre o erro? Vc depurou e obteve a linha do código onde o erro ocorre? Já verificou se o buffer (`ls_buffer_PPouAUT` - aliás, você não colocou o código onde ele é alocado) conseguiu ser alocado para a quantidade de bytes recebida? Sem mais detalhes fica difícil te ajudar.

Comment: Desculpa, sou novo aqui

Comment: Vou editar, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Por nada. Retirei o meu voto pra fechar então. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`recv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) pode devolver `-1` em caso de erro.

Nesse caso, vais tentar aceder a `ls_buffer_PPouAUT[-1]` que origina o erro "SIGSEGV".

Verifica se o recv() correu bem:

```
   ln_retorno_receive = recv(in_socket_handler, ls_buffer_PPouAUT, sizeof ls_buffer_PPouAUT, 0);
   // validacao de erros
   if (ln_retorno_receive < 0) {
       perror("recv");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   ls_buffer_PPouAUT[ln_retorno_receive] = 0;
```

Comment: +1 Exato. Outra coisa possível é o `recv` receber mais do que 2047 bytes (o AP diz que o erro ocorre quando recebe um pacote grande de dados) e então invadir além da memória alocada. Talvez o ideal seja alocar a memória dinamicamente ou (melhor ainda) ajustar o tamanho pré-alocado caso o tamanho recebido o exceda.